# Any things I should be prepared for traveling to DME Moscow on a Pakistani passport from London as a UK resident?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, russia, pakistani-citizens

Not that I anticipate issues, but still interested in knowing. Basically traveling to DME Moscow (pending Visa) in November and I am interested if border control in DME might give me some trouble given I’m a Pakistani citizen, despite having being a lawful UK resident for 8 years, and currently living and working in London.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Russian border officers don't speak English, so if all your papers are in order, they shouldn't say a single thing to you.

Comment: What sort of papers ?

Comment: @Ali Gajani Passport, Visa, any additional requirements eg travel insurance (if this is specified as required)

Comment: I see. Thanks for that information. When was the last time you visited Moscow and why do you say they don’t speak English? I mean they must’ve been trained for the World Cup no?

Comment: @AliGajani I'm not the person you asked, but I visited Moscow earlier this month. I can't say for sure how many *can* speak English, but the border guards I encountered certainly weren't eager to do so - they said a total of four words to me on the way in and out ("sign here" when giving me the immigration card on arrival, and "boarding card" when stamping it on my way out) Be prepared for them to spend a *very* long time looking between you and your passport photo, though.

Comment: @AliGajani Because English knowledge is so uncommon among Russians, that those who know it go for much more advanced professions. Also, papers=passport+visa

Comment: @ChrisH Thank you for this answer Chris. Interesting point you brought up here. I thought the immigration card was to be filled by me in the airplane and handed over to border control. Is that bit deprecated now? Also, what is the reasoning behind stamping a boarding card/pass. Never seen that happen to me before. And yes of course they will, after I've kept a little beard. Haha

Comment: @AliGajani Don't know either the reason to stamp boarding passes on exit, but I know that at least Moldova, Turkey, North Cyprus and Georgia do that too

Comment: There are several different lines in immigration at DME. I find DME to be the absolute worst in Moscow!! The lines make no sense and if you're not Russian, you just have to wait longer, as the Russians cut in line and form their own lines, by waiving their passports in the air. I spent two hours in line there one time and it was a zoo. Since you are not Russian, be prepared to be put into the worst lines of your life. Worse lines than at the peak in Hong Kong or when clearing immigration in Macau. Even the Manila airport is better, IMO.